# form widgets "id" in multiple layouts

Tags: android, layout, multiscreen

I have four different layout (same name) in different folder for different screen size . every layouts have some TextView and ImageView and one button with the same value ! i want to know they should have same id ? for example all buttons in four layouts should have same id ?
i want to use them in my MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you have to use the same id.Because for different screen sizes only you made your layout with different UI changes. If you does not follow the same id,you will get NPE exception when you trying to execute in different screens/devices.

So the id must be same in all four layouts which in different folder.

Thanks

Comment: i do this but my regularity becomes corrupted in other layouts !

Comment: ofcourse!!you have to make design alignment for different screen sizes...

Comment: i just change the size or height in new layout (enough for me) ! what should i do else ?

Comment: What is yout problem exactly?You want to use the same id for all different layouts...For every layout you are going to use single activity right..You your id must be same...If you want your app to be compatible to all screens pls refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes. because you are calling the same layouts(although they are for different screen sizes), but they have the same features.

Comment: same features like what ?

Comment: TextView, ImageView, and one button.